# How to use jQuery forEach statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Note please. (I'm currently using the Spring Framework (MVC))

The value sent from Controller to ajax is ...

[image]

It looks like the picture above.

I am looping through the forEach statement for the values in that array, and I want to put the value into the  tag.

So I wrote the code.

```
$(function()
    {
        $('#doctorSelect').change(function()
        {
            $('#selectGugan').show();

            var doctor_idx = $(this).val();
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'selectDoctor.do',
                data: {"d_idx":doctor_idx},
                dataType: 'JSON',
                success: function(sectionDate)
                {
                    console.log(sectionDate);
                    var html = "<option value=''>Choice Doctor</option>";
                    var responseData = [];
                    responseData.push(sectionDate);
                    console.log(responseData);

                    $.each(responseData, function(key, value)
                    {
                        console.log("forEach statement in responseData :" + responseData);

                        //html+="<option value="+new_date+">"+new_date+"</option>"; 
                    });
                    $('#doctorSelect_2').html(html);
                },
                error: function(sectionDate)
                {
                    console.log("data : " + sectionDate);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

But unexpectedly, I do not get the key, value.

In fact, I don t know about the jquery forEach statement.

How do I set key, value?

I just want to bring those values and express it like this.

```
<option value="ri_idx">ri_startDate ~ ri_endDate</option>
```

How to set key, value or How to use jquery forEach statement ?

I am a beginner. I would appreciate it if you could give me an example.

Comment: `console.log("forEach statement in responseData :" + responseData);` replace this with `console.log(key); console.log(value);` and you will get individual key/val

Comment: OK, I will fix it.

Comment: 0 / [object Object] (key / value)

Comment: well now to get the individual properties of `value`, you can simply do `value.propertyName`, where `propertyName` is whatever is in your response.

Comment: I've already tried it, but it's undifined. for example I write and Test that .. console.log(value.ri_idx) @N.Ivanov

Comment: oh why would you do `responseData.push(sectionDate)`? You can simply do `$.each(sectionDate, function(key, value){ ... });` and then it should work. Hope this helps

Comment: because its an multiple object not array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161278/discussion-between-choiseongwon-and-n-ivanov).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case I am not sure why would you be doing this:

```
responseData.push(sectionData);
```

because this way you dont get an array of objects as I believe you thought you would, you simply will get an array with 1 element in it, which is many objects, so doing a forEach on that array will not help, because the value will be the multiobject element (not a single object that you could access properties).

What you want to do is iterate over your original objects, so your code should be something like this:

```
$.each(sectionDate, function(key, value){
    // here you can access all the properties just by typing either value.propertyName or value["propertyName"]
    // example: value.ri_idx; value.ri_startDate; value.ri_endDate;
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery forEach working like this

```
$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
  alert( key + ": " + value );
});
```

If you are using Array for loop than `key` is `array index` and `value` values and if you are using `javascript object` then `object key` is `key` and `value` is `object value` for the particular `key`.

You can read more at [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

Comment: The answer was obscured. Now I've checked your answer. Your answer also helped me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use property names in object. [Check if this helps](https://jsfiddle.net/21d50jaf/5/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var responseData = [
    {startdate: '2017-12-21', enddate: '2017-12-22', idx: '1'},
    {startdate: '2017-11-21', enddate: '2017-11-22', idx: '1'},
    {startdate: '2017-10-21', enddate: '2017-10-22', idx: '1'}
  ];
  var html = '';
  $.each(responseData, function(key, value) {
    html += "<option value=" + value.startdate + ">" + value.startdate + "</option>";
  });
  $('#doctorSelect').html(html);
});
```